# is there any ctypes.windll documentation?

Tags: python

Is there a webpage where all functions and classes in ctypes is documented?
I would like to read about everything under it.
for example ctypes.windll, is there anything like this:

http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

Comment: Unfortunately the only good source I know of apart from the [official python doc on ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) is http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/reference.html

Comment: That link can now be found in the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20180329093632/http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/reference.html

Comment: Here's a listing of all functions exported by dll files in the Windows/System32/ directory: https://windows10dll.nirsoft.net/

Answer (score 0):

it's actually this i am looking for, 
ctypes.windll is all on MSDN!

Comment: If you come from the future and, like me, would like a link, here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/